# How to fix an error on "my connection.Open" in vb.net express 2010 and ms access 2013?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013

I'm using VB.NET Express 2010 and MS Access 2013. I got an error `"my connection.Open"`. Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form2
    Dim provider As String

    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        dataFile = "C:\Municipal Franchising System.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert into tbrecord([Application], [Last Name], [Suffix], [First Name], [Middel Name], [Street Address], [Barangay], [City], [Plate No], [Make/Brand], [OR No], [Date], [CR No], [Chasis], [Motor No], [Franchise Plate Number], [Application No], [MC], [SIDECAR], [FRONT], [REAR], [MC HEADLIGHT], [SIDECAR HEADLIGHT], [FRONT BRAKES], [REAR BRAKES], [LOUD], [SOFT], [SIDECAR WITH TODA COLOR], [SIDECAR WITHOUT COLOR]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Application", CType(TextBox1.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Last Name", CType(TextBox3.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Suffix", CType(TextBox4.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("First Name", CType(TextBox5.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Middle Name", CType(TextBox6.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Street Address", CType(TextBox2.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Plate No", CType(TextBox7.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Make/ Brand", CType(TextBox8.Text, String)))

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox3.Clear()
            TextBox4.Clear()
            TextBox5.Clear()
            TextBox6.Clear()
            TextBox7.Clear()
            TextBox8.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what the error message was. Hint: you could tell us.

Comment: By the way, if the error occurs on the `Open` call.  Nothing after that is really relevant, so there's not much point posting it. Depending on circumstances, we might ask for more code if we need it but you should try to only post relevant code.

Comment: Check the connection string and provide error details here. I think it may related to something else more than wrongly formed connection string.